# How to boot USB stick in UEFI mode?

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, uefi

we recently bought a new windows 8 laptop, and we are trying to install Ubuntu to it in a dual boot configuration. I downloaded the 64 bit 12.10 iso and put it in a USB stick, both with the utility recommended from the Ubuntu installation guide and with Unetbootin. However, when I reboot the laptop and select from BIOS the USB as first option, it just flashes the Toshiba logo for 2 seconds and then reboots again and does this ad infinitum (I disabled SecureBoot) until I remove the usb stick and then it boots normally into windows. If I however turn on the option CSM/legacy boot in the BIOS I CAN boot into the usb installer, so I don't think it is an issue with the usb stick nor the iso image.

The question is, how do I get it to boot in UEFI mode? Or should I just keep going in legacy mode and hope the installer recognizes the UEFI boot?

Comment: Try this walkthrough: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html

Comment: @Ramhound: How will that walkthrough help with a Linux installation?